# AutoSuggestBox not showing results

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, autosuggest

I'm having trouble displaying the results in the `AutoSuggestBox` on Windows Phone 8.1. I'm using MVVM Light to bind my itemsource to the Autosuggestbox.

```
<AutoSuggestBox Header="Van" Text="{Binding SearchTextFrom, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding suggestionFrom}">
            <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchChangedFrom}">
                    </core:InvokeCommandAction>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </AutoSuggestBox>
```

My ViewModel

```
private RelayCommand _SearchChangedFrom;
        public RelayCommand SearchChangedFrom
        {
            get
            {
                return _SearchChangedFrom ?? (_SearchChangedFrom = new RelayCommand(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.countrycode))
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Could not autocomplete the country because there was no country code provided.");
                            return;
                        }

                        var predictions = await _Service.GetGoogleMapsSuggestionFromQuery(user.countrycode, SearchTextFrom);
                        suggestionFrom = predictions;
                    }));
            }
        }

private List<Prediction> _suggestionFrom;
        public List<Prediction> suggestionFrom
        {
            get { return _suggestionFrom; }
            set
            {
                Set<List<Prediction>>(() => suggestionFrom, ref _suggestionFrom, value);
                Debug.WriteLine(suggestionFrom.Count + " were received. Displayong them in the autosuggestbox");
                foreach (Prediction prediction in _suggestionFrom)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(("Predicition: " + prediction.description));
                }
            }
        }
```

The objects are set and are not null.

[image]

So why don't they show up?

**UPDATE**
My Model

```
 public class Prediction : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _description;
        public string description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set{Set<string>(() => description, ref _description, value);}
        }

        private string _id;

        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; } 
            set { Set<string>(() => id, ref _id, value); }
        }

        private List<MatchedSubstring> _matchedSubstrings;
        public List<MatchedSubstring> matched_substrings
        {
            get { return _matchedSubstrings; }
            set{Set<List<MatchedSubstring>>(() => matched_substrings, ref _matchedSubstrings, value);}
        }

        private string _place_id;

        public string place_id
        {
            get { return _place_id; } 
            set { Set<string>(() => place_id, ref _place_id, value); }
        }

        private string _reference;
        public string reference
        {
            get { return _reference; }
            set { Set<string>(() => reference, ref _reference, value); }
        }

        private List<Term> _terms;

        public List<Term> terms
        {
            get { return _terms; }
            set { Set<List<Term>>(() => terms, ref _terms, value); }
        }

        private List<string> _types;
        public List<string> types
        {
            get { return _types; }
            set { Set<List<String>>(() => types, ref _types, value); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.description;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged*? Can you check if getter is called once you set `suggestionFrom = predictions;`? - put there another Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: I am implementing the interface. The getter is called after the Set method.

Comment: How *Prediction* class correspond to *DataTemplate* - is `description` a vaild property? Can you show this class? As the getter is called I assume that the *DataContext* is set properly.

Comment: I have added my model.
The datacontext is set correctly because I receive the text typed in view.

Comment: I've build a sample basing on your code and it should work. Can you check if it will work if you put `var predictions = new List<Prediction> { new Prediction {description = "item"}};` instead of `var predictions = await _Service.GetGoogleMapsSuggestionFromQuery(user.countrycode, SearchTextFrom);`?

Comment: The item is set then the get is called. The predicition object with description item is returned but nothing is shown on the screen. I don't know if it's important to mention the AutoSuggestBox is implemented in a ContentDialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72773/discussion-between-tim-rijckaert-and-romasz).

Comment: Maybe instead of navigating to other page, you can change Visibility of panels of current Page. For example AB is in Grid which is always invisible until you want it (simulate ContentDialog), along with this you make main Grid invisible.

Comment: I could do that. But the AB should just work out of the box in a ContentDialog. Eventhought I don't see anything else about people also facing this problem.

Comment: I agree that it should work just like that. But hence for now it's not, I'm looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 public ObservableCollection<Prediction> SuggestionFrom { get; set; }
```

instead

```
public List<Prediction> SuggestionFrom { get; set; }
```

ObservableCollection is notify user interface about any changes of your Predictions (add or delete)

Comment: Thta's not it. I'm using the MVVMLight